# Notice: Undefined index: id_no_departamento

Tags: php

Mi código en el que me marca error es este:

```php
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
//Recibir los datos y almacenar en variables 
$id_no_departamento = $_POST["id_no_departamento"];
$nombre_departamento = $_POST["nombre_departamento"];
$con=conectar();
//Consultar para insertar

$insertar = "INSERT INTO departamento(id_no_departamento, nombre_departamento) VALUES ('$id_no_departamento', '$nombre_departamento') ";
//Ejecutar consulta 
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);
if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registarse';
} else {
    echo 'Departamento registrado exitosamente';
}
//Cerrar conexion 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Y mi código con el formulario es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "estilo2.css">

<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","registroservicios") or die ("Error");
 ?>

<html>
     <head>
          <title> Formulario De Departamentos  </title>

          <meta charset="UTF-8">
     </head>

     <body>
          <body>
              <div align="center">    <img src="../../../registroservicios/imagenes/imgsabinas.jpg" align="left"></p></div></h1>
              <br>
              <br>
              <img src="../../../registroservicios/imagenes/imgpeñoles.png" align="right">
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
   <h1> <div align="center">     <p><center></center>SISTEMA DE REGISTRO DE SERVICIOS REALIZADOS A UNIDADES DE MINERA SABINAS  </center> </p></div></h1>
          
              
              
          <form action="registrardepartamento.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar ();">
          <div class="form">
               <form action="#" method="POST">
                   <h1><div align="center"> <body><center> REGISTRO DE  DEPARTAMENTO  NUEVO </center></body></h1>
                    
                    <p>Numero de Departamento </p>
                    <label for="id_no_departamento "></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="numero" name="id_no_departamento " placeholder="id_no_departamento " required>
                    
                    <p>Nombre de Departamento</p>
                    <label for="nombre_departamento"></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre_departamento" placeholder="nombre_departamento" required>

                    <br>
                    
                    <br>

                    <div align="center"> <input type="submit" value="Finalizar"></div>
                     <br>
                    <br>
               </form>
               


    <?php

       if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
         
         $id_no_departamento= $_POST["id_no_departamento"];
         $nombre_departamento = $_POST["nombre_departamento"];
         
         $insertar = "INSERT INTO departamento(id_no_departamento, nombre_departamento ) VALUES ('$id_no_departamento' , '$nombre_departamento')";

         $ejecutar= mysqli_query($con, $insertar);

         if($ejecutar){
          echo "<h3> Insertado correctamente</h3>";

          }

         }
      ?>
         <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Volver</a>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

No me registra, me aparece ese error.

Comment: Hola. Se te escapan espacios en blanco al final, al poner el `name` y el `id` de algunos elementos. Eso es lo que está provocando el problema. Corrige el input así: **`<input type="numero" name="id_no_departamento" placeholder="id_no_departamento" required>`** Corrige los demás elementos que tienen ese espacio en blanco al final, pues no lo mismo esto: `$_POST["id_no_departamento"]` que esto: `$_POST["id_no_departamento "]`.

Comment: Falta otra cosa más, no estás mandando nada con un `name="insert"`, por tanto, nunca entrará en esta parte: `if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {` puedes ponerle ese valor al botón, para que así entre en el `if`, es decir: **`<input type="submit" name="insert" value="Finalizar">`** Debes tener claro que cuando se envía un `form`, el servidor recibe en la supergloblal del método, `$_POST` en este caso, un array asociativo donde las claves son los `name` de los elementos y los valores son los `value` de los mismos. Si no pones el `name`, no encontrarás el dato en la superglobal.

Comment: En lugar de agregar ruido a la pregunta, provee más contexto. No hagas que tu pregunta sea netamente código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código.

- Tienes un desastre en tu HTML. Entre otras cosas, tienes un `form` dentro de otro `form`, lo cual no tiene ningún sentido, además, falta el cierre de uno de esos `form`. Deja un único `form`, puedes poner en el `action` el archivo `.php` y desarrollar allí el código PHP de más abajo. No tiene sentido ese código PHP inicial, deberías delegarlo al archivo del `action`. Tampoco se entiende qué sentido tiene esto: `onsubmit="return validar ();` ¿? Realmente, este tipo de acciones se hacen hoy día vía Ajax o Fetch, pero ese es otro tema.
- Siempre en el HTML, tienes varias etiquetas `body` y elementos que cierras y no abres. O metes cosas dentro de `center` (obsoleto) al tiempo que usas una clase que por su nombre sería para centrar y que sería la forma recomendada. Deberías cuidar la forma en que escribes tu HTML.
- Se te escapan espacios en blanco al final, al poner el `name` y el `id` de algunos elementos. Eso es lo que está provocando el problema. Tú tienes el `input` así:

  ```
    <input type="numero" name="id_no_departamento " placeholder="id_no_departamento" required>
  ```

  Eso hace que en el `$_POST` el dato se serialice así:

  ```
    $_POST=array('id_no_departamento '=>'El Valor que sea');
                                     ^Hay un espacio en blanco
  ```

  En el código estás buscando esto: `$_POST["id_no_departamento"]` pero lo que hay es esto, que no es lo mismo: `$_POST["id_no_departamento "]`.
- Tampoco entrará en el `if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {`, porque no has mandando nada bajo una clave `insert`. Debes tener claro que cuando se envía un `form`, el servidor recibe en la supergloblal del método, $_POST en este caso, un array asociativo donde las claves son los `name` de los elementos y los valores son los `value` de los mismos. Si no pones el `name`, no encontrarás el dato en la superglobal. Puedes usar el `input` de tipo `submit` para esto.

  Finalmente, para evitar los *`Undefined index`* conviene usar ternarios o fusión de null, al momento de recoger las variables, y escribir un código controlado.

Corrigiendo todo lo dicho, tendríamos:

### HTML

He intentado arreglar varios desastres en tu HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo2.css">

<html>

<head>
  <title> Formulario De Departamentos </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <img src="../../../registroservicios/imagenes/imgsabinas.jpg" align="left">
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <img src="../../../registroservicios/imagenes/imgpeñoles.png" align="right">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1>
    <div align="center">
      <p>
        SISTEMA DE REGISTRO DE SERVICIOS REALIZADOS A UNIDADES DE MINERA SABINAS
      </p>
    </div>
  </h1>
  <div class="form">
    <form action="registrardepartamento.php" method="post" class="form-register">
      <h1>
        <div align="center">
          <p>REGISTRO DE DEPARTAMENTO NUEVO</p>
        </div>
      </h1>

      <p>Numero de Departamento </p>
      <label for="id_no_departamento"></label>
      <br>
      <input type="numero" name="id_no_departamento" placeholder="id_no_departamento" required>

      <p>Nombre de Departamento</p>
      <label for="nombre_departamento"></label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="nombre_departamento" placeholder="nombre_departamento" required>

      <br>

      <br>

      <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Finalizar">
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### PHP

Este código debe ir en el archivo **`registrardepartamento.php`** que es el que va a gestionar los envíos del formulario. Cuando el código sea funcional te aconsejo que aprendas a hacer este tipo de operaciones con Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        //Recibir los datos y almacenar en variables 
        $id_no_departamento = $_POST["id_no_departamento"] ?? NULL;
        $nombre_departamento = $_POST["nombre_departamento"] ?? NULL;
        if ($id_no_departamento && $nombre_departamento) {
            include_once ("conexion.php");
            $con=conectar();
        //Consultar para insertar
        
            $insertar = "INSERT INTO departamento(id_no_departamento, nombre_departamento) VALUES ('$id_no_departamento', '$nombre_departamento') ";
            //Ejecutar consulta 
            $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);
            if (!$resultado) {
                echo 'Error al registarse';
            } else {
                echo 'Departamento registrado exitosamente';
            }
            //Cerrar conexion 
            mysqli_close($con);
        } else {
            echo "No se enviaron datos válidos para insertar";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No se apretó el botón de insertar";
    }
```